# Add/remove input boxes to the table row in Angular dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

Somehow I can't get my head around this in angular- I have a Table and want to add the row on-click, but this row should have empty input boxes and a button to remove itself.

```
 <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Test 1</th>
            <th>200</th>
            <th>Add new row</th>
        </tr>
         //I want to Add this part dynamically everytime when I click on Add new row
                <tr>
                     <td>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Please Enter the Address">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Number of Quantity">
                    </td>
         //On Delete it should delete just that particular row
                    <td>Delete</td>
                </tr>

        </tbody>
```

I have created plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/DDj5Z99tw1QuN8xlxZ7V?p=preview just for showing what I am trying to achieve. If anyone would be able to give a hint or link me to tutorial would be great!

Comment: It seems as though you have no knowledge of angular. The plunker does not have an app or a controller. All you need to do is put an `ng-click` wherever you want to add a row, and make the function that gets called add an item to your data source. Check out any basic angular tutorial.

Comment: sorry if I did not made my self clear before. The plunker is created just for giving better understanding to my question. There are plenty of tutorial out there on adding row to the table. But my question is more specific towards adding input box in the table.

Comment: You should have completed the setup in plunker so someone could help you immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Please have look at this plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ogvezWz6WDwDhCnm2bDU

Idea is to use a row at the end whose visibility can be controlled. And using **ngRepeat** you can iteratively display your added product items.

```
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
         <td>
            {{row.product}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{row.quantity}}
        </td>
        <td>
          <button ng-click="deleteRow($index)">Delete</button>
          <button ng-click="addNewRow()">New</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="addrow">
         <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Please Enter the Address" ng-model="product"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Number of Quantity" ng-model="quantity"/>
        </td>
        <td><button ng-click="save()">Save</button> <button ng-click="delete()">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
```

And the Controller code

```
angular.module('AddRow', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.rows = [ { "product": "Test 1", "quantity": "200"}];
  $scope.addrow = false;

  $scope.addNewRow = function(){
    $scope.addrow = true;
  };

  $scope.deleteRow = function(index){
    //delete item from array
    $scope.rows.splice(index,1);
  };

  $scope.save = function(){
    //add item to array
    $scope.rows.push({"product": $scope.product, "quantity": $scope.quantity});
    //reset text input values
    $scope.product = "";
    $scope.quantity = "";
    //hide the add new row
    $scope.addrow = false;
  };

  $scope.delete = function(){
    $scope.addrow = false;
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks mate :). I had a quick look at your solution, the new button only works ones. But great effort.

Comment: So you want to be able to add multiple empty rows with text boxes?

Comment: Yes, that' the problem now I am facing in my actual code :).

Comment: May be using ngHtmlBind could help here somehow. Let me try something quick.

Comment: Now it does what you want for adding multiple rows. Please check the plunker. BUT there is a problem in updating the text input values to the model.

Comment: It seems you can't put angular elements into ng-bind-html. So only option seems to be is writing a directive using compile service.

Comment: Great work mate, much appreciated :) I am working on my solution as well, ones I figure this out will post it here.

Comment: That was my first thought with this problem. Will also give it a try to that.